# Error result for define max value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When I want to select max value from code (code below). It shows me 2 max row result. But I want to get one max value.
Code below:

```
select 
distinct(c.msisdn), 
max(adj_date),
6144 - (round(t.volume /1024/1024,2))as остаток_мб 
from 
subscriber_discount_threads t, 
client_balance c, 
subs_packs p 
where 
t.dctr_dctr_id = 1283 
and p.pack_pack_id in (877,874) 
and c.msisdn = '550350057' 
and t.adj_date >= '30.10.2015' 
and sysdate between p.start_date and p.end_date 
and sysdate between t.start_thread and t.end_thread  
and c.subs_subs_id = t.subs_subs_id 
and p.subs_subs_id = c.subs_subs_id 
group by c.msisdn, t.volume
```

result below (2 row, but i want that shows me only max date)

```
25.11.2015 13:08:06
03.11.2015 11:42:06
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Updated my answer as per OP

```
    with cte as(
        select 
        distinct(c.msisdn) as msisdn, 
        max(adj_date) as maxdate,
        6144 - (round(t.volume /1024/1024,2))as остаток_мб ,
        from 
        subscriber_discount_threads t, 
        client_balance c, 
        subs_packs p 
        where 
        t.dctr_dctr_id = 1283 
        and p.pack_pack_id in (877,874) 
        and c.msisdn = '550350057' 
        and t.adj_date >= '30.10.2015' 
        and sysdate between p.start_date and p.end_date 
        and sysdate between t.start_thread and t.end_thread  
        and c.subs_subs_id = t.subs_subs_id 
        and p.subs_subs_id = c.subs_subs_id 
        group by c.msisdn, t.volume
    ),
    cte2 as(
    select c1.*,row_number over(partition by msisdn order by maxdate desc) as maxdatecol from cte c1)
    select c2.* from cte2 c2 
    where maxdatecol =1
    ;
```

Comment: Thats right. But I want to shows me all column not only date.

Comment: In my query it show like:
№       msisdn                 max(date)                   MB
1 550350057 25.11.2015 13:08:06 2329,15
2 550350057 03.11.2015 11:42:06 -1,4

Comment: 3 column there (msisdn, max(value) and остаток_мб )

Comment: Edited my answer. Check now

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
select 
distinct c.msisdn, 
max(adj_date) over (order by null),
6144 - (round(t.volume /1024/1024,2))as остаток_мб 
from 
subscriber_discount_threads t, 
client_balance c, 
subs_packs p 
where 
t.dctr_dctr_id = 1283 
and p.pack_pack_id in (877,874) 
and c.msisdn = '550350057' 
and t.adj_date >= '30.10.2015' 
and sysdate between p.start_date and p.end_date 
and sysdate between t.start_thread and t.end_thread  
and c.subs_subs_id = t.subs_subs_id 
and p.subs_subs_id = c.subs_subs_id
```

max value will be the same for all rows. It is max date in table. Not sure if it is what you want, but this is how I understand you.

Comment: This is incorrect result. We don't must replace value. The subscriber doesn't have to diferrent value for one day, but only one.

Comment: @MuhammadYakubov your result contains only 2 columns instead of 3. And can you provide example of result which you want to get. Otherwise it is hard to understand what you want (at least for me)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) to get the information

```
select distinct c.msisdn, t.volume, adj_date,
max(adj_date) over (partition by c.msisdn, t.volume) as max_adj_date,
6144 - (round(t.volume /1024/1024,2))as остаток_мб 
from 
subscriber_discount_threads t, 
client_balance c, 
subs_packs p 
where 
t.dctr_dctr_id = 1283 
and p.pack_pack_id in (877,874) 
and c.msisdn = '550350057' 
and t.adj_date >= '30.10.2015' 
and sysdate between p.start_date and p.end_date 
and sysdate between t.start_thread and t.end_thread  
and c.subs_subs_id = t.subs_subs_id 
and p.subs_subs_id = c.subs_subs_id
```